# Add required dependencies to py_wheel

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-python

I am trying to create a wheel package from bazel using `py_wheel`. `py_wheel` has an option to provide the required python dependencies using the `requires` param. However, I don't want to provide the list of dependencies manually. Is there a way that I can read my dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file and provide it in the list in bazel?

```
py_wheel(
    name = "dummy",
    distribution = "dummy",
    python_tag = "py3",
    version = "latest",
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["dummy = dummy.app:main"]},
    requires = [?],
    deps = [":dummy-dependencies"],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the requirements in this way

```
load("@deps_1//:requirements.bzl", deps_1_requirement = "requirement")
```

The attribute option requires is for "List of requirements for this package ". find it [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/main/docs/packaging.md)